# Как распарсить в php двумерный xml в php

Tags: php, xml, парсер

Как в php распарсить xml такого вида:

-<1>
-<1.1> текст < /1.1>
-<1.2>
<1.2.1> текст < /1.2.1>
<1.2.2> текст < /1.2.2>
<1.2.2> текст < /1.2.2>
< /1.2>
< /1>

-<1>
-<1.1> текст < /1.1>
-<1.2>
<1.2.1> текст < /1.2.1>
<1.2.2> текст < /1.2.2>
<1.2.2> текст < /1.2.2>
< /1.2>
< /1>

Answer (score 1):

Короче, я сделал так:
Внешний цикл перебирал элементы большого массива и каждый отдельно сохранял отдельно в переменную xml. а во вложенном цикле уже разбирал эту переменную. в ней одномерные массивы.с помощью simpleXml и  foreach